# Unable to resize Ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Ag-grid not resizing based on its content.The grid gets row and columnData dynamically. Based on the content want to resize the grid.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcCyJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Column Resizing**
[ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/)

All columns can be resized by dragging the top right portion of the column.

**Enable Resizing**
Turn column resizing on for the grid by setting `resizable=true` for each column. To set resizing for each column, set `resizable=true` on the default column definition.

The snippet below allows all columns except Address to be resized by explicitly setting each column.

```
gridOptions: {
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', resizable: true},
        {field: 'age', resizable: true},
        {field: 'address'},
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting your data, you can simply call

```
gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
```

in order to fit yout columns to the grid size.